# Can't reach my SQL Server hosted in a Windows Server VM, any ideas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-cloud-platform, windows-server

Well, I'm having the following situation.

I'm trying to set up a testing environment which consist of having a SQL Server on a Windows Server VM hosted on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). So far I've installed SQL Server on the VM and configured an instance with SQL authentication. Then I installed SMSS to access using the instance name and my credentials. At this point everything works well.

The problem comes when I try to access my SQL Server via SMSS from another computer. As the instance I'm using my GCP VM IP Adress and the credentials I've created before. The error is as follows:

[image: SQL Issue]

So far I've done the following configurations:

- Enable TCP/IP via SQL Server configuration manager.
- I made sure that port 1433 was properly configured in the TCP/IP properties.
- Created a new inbound rule on the Firewall to allow TCP connections using port 1433.
- On the SMSS, checked that allow remote connections is enabled.
- Restarted SQL Services from SQL Server configuration manager and services.msc

With above configurations it should work! But I've no idea what's happening.
Anyone who could give me a hint of how this could be solved, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You mentioned "instance name" when talking about the local installations and testing on the VM itself. Is it actually the default "MSSQLSERVER" instance name or is it something else? If it's different than it's probably listening on a different port than 1433. You can confirm this by opening SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager and checking the TCP/IP Protocol settings inside the instance's Server Protocols settings. You could also try forcing SSMS to use the TCP/IP protocol by entering `34.176.3.148,1433` in the Server name field.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for your reply. Indeed, the instance is MSSQLSERVER. Forgot to mention! On the other hand, already tried forcing SMSS by adding a ',' and then the port.

Comment: "On the SMSS, checked that allow remote connections is enabled." That option is not relevant and [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: You've checked the Windows Firewall settings on the VM itself, I assume, but what about the VPC firewall rules for the VPC in which the VM resides?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning YES! I configured it via VPC Firewall rules on GCP and it worked! Thank you!!!